# Which is considered as the highest form of generosity according to Hinduism?

Tags: belief, daana

A person can donate his time, money etc etc. Which of these *Daana* is considered the highest according to Hindu beliefs?

Comment: See Gita Chapter 17 verses 20-22. Its not what you give, but your attitude in giving.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda: Yup, I have read that. I believe its both what you give and with what attitude you give.

Comment: You are adding more to the Gita then what it says.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda swamiji , will you please help me on this:- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15412/do-hinduism-supports-concept-of-continues-charity