# Donation of food is higher than donation of other things?

Tags: mahabharata

I have heard that Karna after death was asked by Dharmaraj for donation of food. Karna denied that he did not give donation of food and was asked to take birth again because donation of food is higher than donation of any other things.

What do scriptures say about this incidence?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitru_Paksha#Legend) (para 2) wikipedia article states similar story in Mahabharata

Comment: Saint Purandaradasa has also stated that Annadana is the best Dana. And I think it is also there in Sundara Kanda of Valmiki Ramayana.

Comment: Hi Parth , please share if you have got any document related to food donation as highest form of donation? (not regarding karna)

Comment: Feeding cow is considered auspicious that gives anything and donating food on amavasya or purnima get one out of rid of pitru dosha.

Comment: Donating chana dal on Monday makes marriage early. Similarly donating milk makes happy marriage on time.

Comment: Related to https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11921/which-is-considered-as-the-highest-form-of-generosity-according-to-hinduism though that question also doesn't have an answer.