# Does Hinduism support the concept of "continued charity"?

Tags: belief, karma, daana

Concept of charity does exist in Hinduism and is termed a Daana.
But does Hinduism support the concept of continued charity??

Continued charity :-
Effect of charity which remains till its demolition.
Eg. Suppose a person donates Rs.5000/- for school construction.
Then he will get its punnya according to his contribution not only once, but till the school building gets demolished.

Note :- School is just a example of good work we can consider other examples like Water Pump in remote village, mandir construction etc. through which many people will continuously be benefited.

Comment: the karmic effects of the charity will continue but they only give good karmas for getting better effects in a loka; and the time in any loka from good karma eventually ends in rebirth. It is not a help in Liberation.

Comment: See Swami Vivekananda Complete Works, V7, p 69 (Here under the heading "Inspired Talks" sub-heading "Thursday July 25." - http://cwsv.belurmath.org/volume_7/vol_7_frame.htm)

Comment: It is said that the person who has done punya karma has a place in heaven as long as he is remembered for his good deeds. So, yes, continued charity is supported. In your e.g., if people remember the contributions of donors even after the school is demolished, it still continues to give good effects to the donor.